# Mobile Browser support

Tags: html, css

I have a code that I only want to display in mobile browsers; not laptops, desktops, etc... (anything bigger than 400px) but I can't seem to get the code to work. Nothing happens when I try it. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ByDAA/24/

Here's the media query

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 400px) {
  #images { display: none; }   /* hide it elsewhere */
}
```

Comment: `@media screen and (min-width: 0px; max-width: 400px) {` Haven't used a media query in a while, and I'm not really sure, but try this.

Comment: @Ariane It doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#images
```

should be

```
.images
```

I make these kinds of mistakes all the time!

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kqwm7/) - working

Comment: I'm still able to view it in my Laptop browser though. Should it be disable when I publish it to my website?

Comment: I use the following tool to help me in these situations: [Window Resizer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh). If you have access to Chrome, it's very helpful. This will help you determine whether or not your breakpoint is exactly at 400px. I suspect that your laptop's monitor is larger than 400px?

Comment: I whipped this up for you: (Screensizer)[http://jsfiddle.net/hwRaK/]. It'll tell you how big your screen is via simple jQuery.

Comment: No problem! That link should have been: www.jsfiddle.net/hwRaK/

Answer (score 0):

Here is this what you wanted OP? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/egpbx